# Import single OBJ files into Maya, moving and rotating it with Python/MEL

Tags: python, import, rendering, maya

Hi I have this code to import OBJ files into maya with Python

**

```js
import maya.cmds as cmds

pathOfFiles = "/Path/to/the/files/folder/"
fileType = "obj"

files = cmds.getFileList(folder=pathOfFiles, filespec='*.%s' % fileType)
if len(files) == 0:
    cmds.warning("No files found")
else:
    for f in files:
        cmds.file(pathOfFiles + f, i=True)
```

**

It imports all the obj files which are into that folder.

However, what I need is:

1. Import an individual OBJ file at once
2. Move and rotate the imported file
3. Apply a Material already created in Maya
4. Render
5. Delete the file
   6 Repeat the process with the next file

Is it possible to do it with Python or MEL

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a fun challenge, so here's my attempt at answering it:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import glob

#1. Import an individual OBJ file at once
def importFile(i):
    cmds.file(i, i=True, groupReference=True, groupName="myobj")

#2. Move and rotate the imported file
def moveFile():
    cmds.select("myobj")
    # Add the X,Y,Z cordinates to change scale, translate and rotate below
    cmds.scale(1,1,1)
    cmds.move(0,0,0)
    cmds.rotate(0,90,0)

#3. Apply a Material already created in Maya
    def materialFile():
    cmds.select("myobj")
    myMaterial = "lambert2" + "SG" #replace lambert2 with your material
    cmds.sets(forceElement=myMaterial)

#4. Render
def renderFile(i):
    cmds.setAttr("defaultRenderGlobals.imageFilePrefix", i, type="string")
    cmds.render(batch=True)

#5. Delete the imported file
def deleteFile():
    cmds.select("myobj")
    cmds.delete()

# Add the path to your obj files. Make sure to leave the /*.obj at the end
myglob = glob.glob("/Users/OSX/Desktop/objs/*.obj") 

for i in myglob:
    importFile(i)
    moveFile()
    materialFile()
    renderFile(i)
    deleteFile()
```

Because you have a list of individual things you need the script to do I've divided up each requirement on your list into its own function. This should make the script more modular and hopefully easy to edit and reuse.

Python works much better for this kind of task because MEL doesn't have functions, instead it has procedures which act like functions but don't work as well from what I've experienced.

Comment: Hello Mr K, Thanks for the answer. It seems to be working after I changed some variables. However, there are some issues I can't fix. 
First, it saves the images in the same folder where the obj are placed but they can't be opened. There are only the files as png and exr.
Also, It doesn't apply the material. change the variable myMaterial for one created in maya but still it doesn't get it.
How can apply more than one material? the objects need two materials.
How can I set up more than one render camera?

cheers

Comment: Hi @Mr-k I've got one issue and it's that it only applies one blinn shader to the whole piece and no more. I need to apply Maxwell Render materiales and set up maxwell as a renderer.

Comment: For anyone wondering what the main difference between a function and a procedure is;  a function returns a value (though that value may be None),  while a procedure does not.